# What is the best way to give a model access to params hash in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, model-view-controller, parameters

This appears to be a violation of MVC, so I'll explain what I am trying to do:

My model makes a call to an API, and the URI of the API depends on the params hash. (The params hash stores the URL of the Rails app).

I created a module to mix into the model (because the model has nothing to do with the API call), but haven't figured out how to get the params into the module.

If possible, I would like to initialize the module with the params hash, but don't know where to do it. `before_create` on the model would work, but that is in the `model.rb` file which doesn't know about the params.

Comment: Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem. Also, include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Don't really understand what you're trying to do. For instance, you haven't explained why you can't just pass in the params hash or parts of it to the model from the controller (which you often do in Rails).

Comment: Why not just pass parameters to the method? `Model.method(params)`

Comment: Because I don't think passing the params is a good way of doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple ideas, depending on your needs:

Pass the parameters to the model with each call, if they change that much. You could do a class method or instance method -

```
Model.api_call params[:field]
@model.api_call params[:field]
```

Save the parameters as class variables in the model:

```
Model.set_parameters(params)

def self.set_parameters(params)
  @@params = params
end

# access it in methods with @@params
```